# close() was never explicitly called on database when clicking back button on activity

Tags: android, database

I am getting this error in products search app that is not crashing but is obviously having database related problems when i click back button (going back from item's details - "DetaljiProizvoda.java" activity) in emulator (that's when this error shows up in Logcat) 
Some new entries that i put with values.put doesn't seem to show up when i search for them, others appear in searh results.

```
09-05 21:01:23.082: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(758): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
09-05 21:01:48.901: I/dalvikvm(813): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-05 21:01:48.951: I/dalvikvm(813): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-05 21:01:49.401: I/dalvikvm(813): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-05 21:01:49.451: I/dalvikvm(813): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-05 21:01:49.741: D/gralloc_goldfish(813): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-05 21:01:49.901: I/dalvikvm(813): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-05 21:01:49.951: I/dalvikvm(813): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-05 21:02:06.762: I/dalvikvm(813): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-05 21:02:06.781: I/dalvikvm(813): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-05 21:02:28.111: D/dalvikvm(813): GC_CONCURRENT freed 143K, 3% free 9386K/9671K, paused 8ms+31ms
09-05 21:02:28.122: E/SQLiteDatabase(813): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/hr.punctum.LociranjePonudaProizvoda/databases/proizvodidb' 
09-05 21:02:28.122: E/SQLiteDatabase(813): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
09-05 21:02:28.122: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1943)
09-05 21:02:28.122: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1007)
09-05 21:02:28.122: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:986)
09-05 21:02:28.122: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1051)
09-05 21:02:28.122: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:770)
09-05 21:02:28.122: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
09-05 21:02:28.122: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
09-05 21:02:28.122: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at hr.punctum.LociranjePonudaProizvoda.DetaljiProizvoda.onCreate(DetaljiProizvoda.java:24)
09-05 21:02:28.122: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
09-05 21:02:28.122: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-05 21:02:28.122: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
09-05 21:02:28.122: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
09-05 21:02:28.122: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
09-05 21:02:28.122: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
09-05 21:02:28.122: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-05 21:02:28.122: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-05 21:02:28.122: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-05 21:02:28.122: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-05 21:02:28.122: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-05 21:02:28.122: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-05 21:02:28.122: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-05 21:02:28.122: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-05 21:02:28.202: E/System(813): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
09-05 21:02:28.332: E/System(813): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Don't have database lock!
09-05 21:02:28.332: E/System(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyLockOwner(SQLiteDatabase.java:2090)
09-05 21:02:28.332: E/System(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.entryRemoved(SQLiteDatabase.java:2182)
09-05 21:02:28.332: E/System(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.entryRemoved(SQLiteDatabase.java:2178)
09-05 21:02:28.332: E/System(813):  at android.util.LruCache.trimToSize(LruCache.java:197)
09-05 21:02:28.332: E/System(813):  at android.util.LruCache.evictAll(LruCache.java:285)
09-05 21:02:28.332: E/System(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.deallocCachedSqlStatements(SQLiteDatabase.java:2143)
09-05 21:02:28.332: E/System(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.closeClosable(SQLiteDatabase.java:1126)
09-05 21:02:28.332: E/System(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.finalize(SQLiteDatabase.java:1914)
09-05 21:02:28.332: E/System(813):  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:182)
09-05 21:02:28.332: E/System(813):  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
09-05 21:02:28.332: E/System(813):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-05 21:02:28.511: E/SQLiteDatabase(813): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/hr.punctum.LociranjePonudaProizvoda/databases/proizvodidb' 
09-05 21:02:28.511: E/SQLiteDatabase(813): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
09-05 21:02:28.511: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1943)
09-05 21:02:28.511: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1007)
09-05 21:02:28.511: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:986)
09-05 21:02:28.511: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1051)
09-05 21:02:28.511: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:770)
09-05 21:02:28.511: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
09-05 21:02:28.511: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
09-05 21:02:28.511: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at hr.punctum.LociranjePonudaProizvoda.DetaljiProizvoda.onCreate(DetaljiProizvoda.java:24)
09-05 21:02:28.511: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
09-05 21:02:28.511: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-05 21:02:28.511: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
09-05 21:02:28.511: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
09-05 21:02:28.511: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
09-05 21:02:28.511: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
09-05 21:02:28.511: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-05 21:02:28.511: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-05 21:02:28.511: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-05 21:02:28.511: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-05 21:02:28.511: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-05 21:02:28.511: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-05 21:02:28.511: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-05 21:02:28.511: E/SQLiteDatabase(813):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-05 21:02:28.552: E/System(813): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
09-05 21:02:28.601: E/System(813): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Don't have database lock!
09-05 21:02:28.601: E/System(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyLockOwner(SQLiteDatabase.java:2090)
09-05 21:02:28.601: E/System(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.entryRemoved(SQLiteDatabase.java:2182)
09-05 21:02:28.601: E/System(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$1.entryRemoved(SQLiteDatabase.java:2178)
09-05 21:02:28.601: E/System(813):  at android.util.LruCache.trimToSize(LruCache.java:197)
09-05 21:02:28.601: E/System(813):  at android.util.LruCache.evictAll(LruCache.java:285)
09-05 21:02:28.601: E/System(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.deallocCachedSqlStatements(SQLiteDatabase.java:2143)
09-05 21:02:28.601: E/System(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.closeClosable(SQLiteDatabase.java:1126)
09-05 21:02:28.601: E/System(813):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.finalize(SQLiteDatabase.java:1914)
09-05 21:02:28.601: E/System(813):  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:182)
09-05 21:02:28.601: E/System(813):  at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
09-05 21:02:28.601: E/System(813):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
package hr.punctum.LociranjePonudaProizvoda;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "proizvodidb";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        /*
         * Kreiranje tabele proizvodi i punjenje tabele sa podacima.
         * Kasnije cu prebaciti ove hardcore kodirane statment-e u XML datoteku.
         */
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS proizvodi (" +
                        "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                        "naziv TEXT, " +
                        "tvrtka TEXT, " +
                        "cijena TEXT, " +
                        "kategorija TEXT, " +
                        "telefonTvrtke TEXT, " +
                        "adresaTvrtke TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(sql);

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put("naziv", "Canon 60D");
        values.put("tvrtka", "Protis");
        values.put("cijena", "4600");
        values.put("kategorija", "fotoaparati");
        values.put("telefonTvrtke", "016587176");
        values.put("adresaTvrtke", "Laducka 36A");
        db.insert("proizvodi", "tvrtka", values);

        values.put("naziv", "Nikon D800");
        values.put("tvrtka", "MagazinRS");
        values.put("cijena", "21600");
        values.put("kategorija", "fotoaparati");
        values.put("telefonTvrtke", "454562542");
        values.put("adresaTvrtke", "Laniste 1B");       
        db.insert("proizvodi", "tvrtka", values);   

        values.put("naziv", "Olympus OM-D");
        values.put("tvrtka", "Telebit");
        values.put("cijena", "5200");
        values.put("kategorija", "fotoaparati");
        values.put("telefonTvrtke", "5657676");
        values.put("adresaTvrtke", "Laniste 1B");       
        db.insert("proizvodi", "tvrtka", values);

        values.put("naziv", "Pentax K-7");
        values.put("tvrtka", "Svijet medija");
        values.put("cijena", "7400");
        values.put("kategorija", "fotoaparati");
        values.put("telefonTvrtke", "11236676");
        values.put("adresaTvrtke", "Laniste 1B");       
        db.insert("proizvodi", "tvrtka", values);

        values.put("naziv", "Samsung S3");
        values.put("tvrtka", "Svijet medija");
        values.put("cijena", "4200");
        values.put("kategorija", "mobiteli");
        values.put("telefonTvrtke", "7814442222");
        values.put("adresaTvrtke", "Laniste 1B");       
        db.insert("proizvodi", "tvrtka", values);

        values.put("naziv", "Samsung S2");
        values.put("tvrtka", "Svijet medija");
        values.put("cijena", "3200");
        values.put("kategorija", "mobiteli");
        values.put("telefonTvrtke", "7814442222");
        values.put("adresaTvrtke", "Laniste 1B");       
        db.insert("proizvodi", "tvrtka", values);

        values.put("naziv", "Huawei U8650");
        values.put("tvrtka", "MagazinRS");
        values.put("cijena", "3200");
        values.put("kategorija", "mobiteli");
        values.put("telefonTvrtke", "7814442222");
        values.put("adresaTvrtke", "Laniste 1B");       
        db.insert("proizvodi", "tvrtka", values);

        values.put("naziv", "Huawei U8660");
        values.put("tvrtka", "MagazinRS");
        values.put("cijena", "3200");
        values.put("kategorija", "mobiteli");
        values.put("telefonTvrtke", "7814442222");
        values.put("adresaTvrtke", "Laniste 1B");       
        db.insert("proizvodi", "tvrtka", values);

        values.put("naziv", "Huawei U8660");
        values.put("tvrtka", "MagazinRS");
        values.put("cijena", "3400");
        values.put("kategorija", "mobiteli");
        values.put("telefonTvrtke", "7814442222");
        values.put("adresaTvrtke", "Laniste 1B");       
        db.insert("proizvodi", "tvrtka", values);

        //db.close();   
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS proizvodi");
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

---

**ListaProizvoda.java**

```
package hr.punctum.LociranjePonudaProizvoda;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class ListaProizvoda extends ListActivity {

    protected EditText searchText;
    protected SQLiteDatabase db;
    protected Cursor cursor;
    protected ListAdapter adapter;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
        searchText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.searchText);

    }    

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void search(View view) {
        // || je operacija spajanja u SQLiteu, slijedeci sql query vraca rezultat iz baze svih zapisa koji pocinju na slovo uneseno u search polje
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, naziv, tvrtka, cijena FROM proizvodi WHERE naziv LIKE ?", 
                        new String[]{searchText.getText().toString() + "%"}); 
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.proizvodi_list_artikl,cursor,new String[] {"naziv", "tvrtka", "cijena"},new int[] {R.id.naziv, R.id.tvrtka, R.id.cijena});
        setListAdapter(adapter);    

    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //kreiranje Intenta za komunikaciju s drugim activity-om
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetaljiProizvoda.class);
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
        //slanje varijable
        intent.putExtra("PROIZVODI_ID", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

---

**DetaljiProizvoda.java**

```
package hr.punctum.LociranjePonudaProizvoda;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DetaljiProizvoda extends Activity {

    protected TextView naziv;
    protected TextView kategorija;
    protected TextView tvrtka;
    protected TextView telefonTvrtke;
    protected TextView adresaTvrtke;
    protected int proizvodId;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.detalji_proizvoda);
        //hvatanje parametra (ID iz tablice) Intenta iz ListaProizvoda activity-a
        proizvodId = getIntent().getIntExtra("PROIZVODI_ID", 0);
        SQLiteDatabase db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT proizv._id, proizv.naziv, proizv.tvrtka, proizv.cijena, proizv.kategorija, proizv.telefonTvrtke, proizv.adresaTvrtke FROM proizvodi proizv LEFT OUTER JOIN proizvodi mgr ON proizv._id = mgr._id WHERE proizv._id = ?", 
                new String[]{""+proizvodId});

        if (cursor.getCount() == 1)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            naziv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.naziv);
            naziv.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("naziv"))); /*+ " " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lastName")));*/

            kategorija = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.kategorija);
            kategorija.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("kategorija")));

            tvrtka = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvrtka);
            tvrtka.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("tvrtka")));

            telefonTvrtke = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.telefonTvrtke);
            telefonTvrtke.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("telefonTvrtke")));

            adresaTvrtke = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.adresaTvrtke);
            adresaTvrtke.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("adresaTvrtke")));

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply close your `cursors` and `db` in `onDestroy()` to stop the "database never closed" messages:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Also `id` in this method already refers to the appropriate row:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //kreiranje Intenta za komunikaciju s drugim activity-om
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetaljiProizvoda.class);
    //slanje varijable 
    intent.putExtra("PROIZVODI_ID", id);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I hope that helps!

---

**Added from comments**

I missed that you were opening your database in `DetaljiProizvoda` as well, basically anywhere you call `getWritableDatabase()` you need to call `close()` when you are done. You can set up `DetaljiProizvoda` just like `ListaProizvoda` (by declaring `db` and `cursor` as class variables and copying the `onDestroy()` method). But because you only read the database once, simply add this to the bottom of `onCreate()` in `DetaljiProizvoda`:

```
cursor.close();
db.close();
```

You asked:

> Aren't these methods (onResume and onDestroy) already implemented in every activity?

Yes, this is why we use `@Override` and `super` when we `extend` a class. In our case, `@Override` tells the compiler to use our version of `onCreate()`, `onDestroy()`, etc. and if we want to call the parent class' version we use the `super` keyword. You don't need to override most parent methods. You are not required to override Activity's `onCreate()`, but then this app wouldn't do much without your `onCreate()` code...

Comment: Thanks. Where to add those methods and lines? I'm beginner in Android, so i am not sure exactly of that.

Comment: All three of these methods go in `ListaProizvoda`, obviously you will replace your existing `onListItemClick()` with this new one.

Comment: i've tried that, app is crashing now. Aren't these methods (onResume and onDestroy) already implemented in every activity? I realize that i need to close database or cursor object and refresh my Cursor somewhere, however.

Comment: thank you Sam, after putting those lines to the bottom of DetaljiProizvoda.java now it is working without error! i just need to deinstall app and installing it again to see new record entered in database (added with put method). i don't know the reason for that (i get "couldn't get connection factory client error" only in logcat).

Comment: If you ever change the code inside your `DatabaseHelper`'s `onCreate()` you can uninstall and reinstall (as you know) or just increase the version number in your constructor `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);`.

Comment: oh thanks, i experimented with that but didn't realize what was happening. this code is part of my diploma thesis app (i need to add location tracker for these items too). you've provided some great answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void search(View view) {
    // || je operacija spajanja u SQLiteu, slijedeci sql query vraca rezultat iz baze svih zapisa koji pocinju na slovo uneseno u search polje
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, naziv, tvrtka, cijena FROM proizvodi WHERE naziv LIKE ?", 
            new String[]{searchText.getText().toString() + "%"}); 
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.proizvodi_list_artikl,cursor,new String[] {"naziv", "tvrtka", "cijena"},new int[] {R.id.naziv, R.id.tvrtka, R.id.cijena});
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    cursor.close();  // Add this line
    db.close(); // And this line as well

}
```

Comment: app is crashing down when adding these lines, i.e. typing first letter and clicking search button. i've tried that before.

Comment: Yeah I was going to change my answer but @Sam has a better answer for you. Go in that direction and you'll be all set.